# ¿Cómo terminar un programa al cumplir una condición en Java?

Tags: java

Quiero saber cómo terminar un programa antes de tiempo al cumplirse determinada condición. Sé que `break;` se puede utilizar adentro de `while` o `switch`; pero hay alguna forma de hacer ésto fuera de estos dos?

```java
respuesta = input.nextLine();
    
if (respuesta.equals("n")){
  --- terminar programa ---
```

Comment: buscas system.exit?

Comment: nose, cuando lo quiero agregar System.exit(int); no funciona

Comment: No funciona que quiere decir?

Comment: @Mr.ToxicMan has probado con return ??

Comment: no funciona quiere decir que no corre el programa @gbianchi. return es para funciones, no es puede usar en el Main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que buscas:

```
System.exit(1);
```

El argumento del método `System.exti()` denota el código de terminación. Puede ser `0` (ok) o `no-0` (terminación extraña). Siendo `no-0` un valor positivo o negativo (`-1`,`1`). Generalmente el número positivo es una salida por error controlado y el negativo por error no controlado o error de sistema.

Comment: una pregunta, el (1) puede ser otra cosa? en que afecta ese uno?

Comment: @Mr.ToxicMan deberias leer el manual de la funcion, lo buscaste en google?

Comment: ahora si!! ya esta

Comment: El argumento del método System.exti() denota el código de terminación. Puede ser 0 (ok) o no-0 (terminación extraña). Siendo no-0 puede ser un valor positivo o negativo (-1,1), generalmente número positivo es una salida por error controlado y negativo por error no controlado o error de sistema.